# pEP - Decrypt-on-sending, filters and Tbird

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with Thunderbird. Since the last set of upgrades to Thunderbird I am getting

"Applying filter pEp-Decrypt-on-Sending failed. Would you like to continue applying filters?"

everytime I send a mail. Only TBird has changed. Does anyone have any idea what this is all about? I don't seem to be able to find any starting points anywhere.

It's TBird 78.7.1 (64bit) BTW

Answer (score 0):

It appears that somehow a "pEp-Decrypt-on-Sending" filter had been activated.

Removed and the messages seem to disappear. Still unsure howe it got set. There are some suggestions of odd behaviour [in Mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2949233)  for earlier versions, although that should have gone away long ago.